# Digimess dual linear PSU

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, linear

Digimess (UK) seem to have gone to the wall, broken links on their website and phone line unobtainable. I wanted try and get the circuit diagram for my LM3002 Dual 30V 1A supply because the +ve side has developed a fault. It won't settle to a stable voltage between about 0 and 20V.
Would anybody have one or something similar?
I have opened the box and the design seems to use LM regulators, Op Amps, a few power transistors and a relay. The negative side is an exact match to the positive even down the regulators. I haven't tried to trace the circuit but it looks like something like this:
The design seems to use different Transformer secondaries to provide three steps of AC Voltage as there are three bridge rectifiers, one each for the LM7805, and the LM7812 and then a high power one for the 2N3055 TRs for the high current output. A 741 OP amp looks to be used in the lower voltage/current section and a Quad Op Amp LM324 and LM313 TR for the medium voltage current.
I hope that give someone enough of a description for a circuit diagram to found/suggested.
Thanks

Comment: Have you taken any pictures of the device? Can you reverse engineer a schematic?

Comment: (The company was dissolved in 2020, [according to Companies House](https://find-and-update.company-information.service.gov.uk/company/02514925).)

Comment: Have you inspected it for any faulty electrolytic capacitors? Are there any burnt-looking resistors or other components evident?

Comment: I have some photos I will see what I can load up. Reverse engineering could be hard and I am concerned I could cause more faults taking it apart. I did do a visual check of the electrolytics etc and there was nothing obvious. Failing to get a schematic my next step was to measure and compare voltages with the -ve circuit. Photo here https://photos.app.goo.gl/S9uYp3zPAQ7TBAN77